# Sending result of zxing barcode scanner in another class to Main class and activity

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm new to Java and Android so some errors might be basic.

I have created two classes: `Rdiet_Main.java` and `Rdiet_Zxing.java`. Everything used to be in the same class but I wanted to keep one functionality per class.

When the scan button is pressed this happens in **Rdiet_Main**:

```
Rdiet_Zxing zxScan = new Rdiet_Zxing();
   zxScan.acquireBarcode(this);
```

Then it goes in the **Rdiet_Zxing**:

```
public void acquireBarcode(Rdiet_Main t){

    IntentIntegrator scanBarcodeIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(t);
    scanBarcodeIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
public String onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanBarcodeResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(scanBarcodeResult != null){
        String strResult;
        strResult = scanBarcodeResult.getContents();
        return strResult;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to send the barcode to **Rdiet_Main**. How should I change my code to make it possible?

### **EDIT :**

I now use `startActivityForResult`. However the scanner isn't launched when the button is pressed and the app just crashes (Unable to find explicit Activity Class in AndroidManifest.xml) . I think **Rdiet_Zxing** needs to be linked to a CaptureActivity or something similar.

Here's what's inside my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Rdiet_Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

### **EDIT2 :**

Updated `Rdiet_Zxing.java`:

```
public class Rdiet_Zxing extends Activity{

    public static final int SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE = 1;
    public static final int FAILURE_RETURN_CODE = 2;

    public void acquireBarcode(Rdiet_Main t){

        IntentIntegrator scanBarcodeIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(t);
        scanBarcodeIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanBarcodeResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(scanBarcodeResult != null){
            String strResult;
            strResult = scanBarcodeResult.getContents();
            //SOL1
            Intent intentResult = new Intent();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("myResult", strResult);
            intentResult.putExtras(b);
            setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intentResult);
            finish();
            //-------------
        }
        else{
            setResult(FAILURE_RETURN_CODE, null);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated `Rdiet_Main.java`:

```
//Scan button
                    Intent i = new Intent(Rdiet_Main.this, Rdiet_Zxing.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    //ScanResult

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                strBarcode = b.getString("myResult");
                tbxAPIbarcode.setText(strBarcode);

            }
        }
```

Comment: what are the error you are having

Comment: @Moudiz I don't understand how to use the returned `strResult` to send it to `Rdiet_Main`. No errors yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all these events in the same class or you can use 'sub activity'.

**Edit**: Here is example

In your main activity, when you press the button:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Rdiet_Main.this, Rdiet_Zxing.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then, you will start the scanner. When you get your result:

```
public String onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
IntentResult scanBarcodeResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if(scanBarcodeResult != null){
    String strResult;
    strResult = scanBarcodeResult.getContents();
    //Add these lines
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("myResult", strResult);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
    finish();
    //-------------
    return strResult;
}
else{
    return null;
}
```

}

Also in scanner activity add this as global:

```
public static final int SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE = 1;
```

And in main activity:

```
private static final int SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

Finally, to get your result in main:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bundle b = data.getExtras();
        String result = b.getString("myResult");
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**

When you create a new activity it must be added to your manifest but if it's not, you can add like this,

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".Rdiet_Main">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- added here -->
<activity android:name=".Rdiet_Zxing"></activity>
</application>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know sub activities require `startActivityForResult` but I don't know how I should use it with Zxing.

Comment: I tried using it but I have errors with the `setResult` and the `finish();` in **onActivityResult** (cannot resolve method). Other question, Should I write anything in the **acquireBarcode** method?

Comment: setResult() method is coming from Activity. Did you extend it ?

Comment: By the way, i think you don't have to return your string in onActivityResult.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to extend it and onActivityResult didn't need to return the string.

However, I realized one of my problem is that Zxing scanner isn't in my **AndroidManifest.xml** so the app keeps crashing. How can I bind the scanner to an existing Activity?

Comment: Can you share your Manifest.xml ?

Comment: I added the `AndroidManifest.xml` to the initial post, hope it helps understand my problem.

Comment: is Rdiet_Zxing an activity ? If yes, you need to implement it in your manifest.

Comment: I see. However my Activity is empty and the scanner doesn't launch. Is there a way to use `acquireBarcode` as soon as the activity starts?

Comment: I edited the post and added `Rdiet_Zxing.java`. Thank you for your time

Comment: Your second class is not an activity. Create a new activity named Rdiet_Zxing and move your acquireBarcode codes to onCreate method. Hope it helps.

Comment: **Fixed it!** Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

- create a callback like below

  ```
  public interface CallbackToMain {

  void result(String scanvalue);

  }
  ```
- Implement it on your **Redit_Main** Activity.
- create object  of Rdiet_Zxing class inside **Redit_Main** and pass interface reference.

  ```
  Rdiet_Zxing zxScan = new Rdiet_Zxing(this); // this refered to callback interface.

  zxScan.acquireBarcode();
  ```
- Inside Redit_Zxing do things like below.

  ```
   CallbackToMain callback;
   public void Rdiet_Zxing(CallbackToMain callback){
   this.callback=callback;
   }


   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   callback.result("your scanned value");
   }
  ```